# странная ошибка читайте основную часть

Tags: javascript, бот

```
var templates = [
{
  "q": ["привет", "hello", "приветик", "ку", "hallo", "бонжур", "bonjour", "кукусики", "приветули", "здравствуй", "здравствуйте"],
  "a": ["Привет, привет!", "Hello!", "Приветик!"]
},

{
  "q": ["как дела", "как жизнь", "как делишки", "привет как дела"],
  "a": ["Спасибо, хорошо, а у Вас?", "Обстановка по кайфу... А как у вас?"]
},

];
```

```
function chatting(templates){
  
  this.templates = templates;

  this.input = $("#input").val().toLowerCase();

  this.tempLen = this.templates.length;

  this.inLen = this.input.length;
  
  printClient();

  this.notUnderstand = true;

  this.input = ignorePunct(this.input);

  for(var i = 0; i < tempLen; i++){
    let len = this.templates[i].q.length;
    for(var x = 0; x < len; x++){
      if(this.input == this.templates[i].q[x]){
        
        let aLen = this.templates[i].a.length - 1;
        let rand = random(aLen)
        printVanja(this.templates[i].a[rand]);
        this.notUnderstand = false;
      }
    }
  }
  if(this.notUnderstand){
    printVanja("НЕ ПОНЕЛ");
  }
  return false;
}
```

ошибка в том, что при передаче некоторых слов например: приветик, бот пишет НЕ ПОНЕЛ, хотя это слово есть в шаблоне, но при этом П,р.!иВе;т!!! он читает и выводит рандомное сообщение, но возможно что такая же ошибка распрастроняется и на ответы.

Comment: я понял одну закономерность: все q, что больше 7 символов пропускаются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторил код, выкинул все лишнее и он работал с "приветик". Тогда оставил всё, что только можно оставить -

Скорее всего у вас ошибка тут:

```
    let aLen = this.templates[i].a.length - 1;
    let rand = random(aLen)
    printVanja(this.templates[i].a[rand]);
```

если `random` - это `Math.random`, то она выдает не целое число чаще всего и тогда переход куда-то в массив будет невозможно и надо делать так:

```
let rand = Math.ceil(Math.random(aLen))
```

Comment: random это Math.round(Math.random * num) поэтому вряд ли он виновник проблемы

`function random(num){
  this.num = num;
  this.output = Math.round(Math.random() * this.num);
  return this.output`

Comment: @Vhacki, ну так доведите свой код до состояния нормального воспроизводимого примера, чтобы отвечающие не гадали, что за `random` или `printVanja`.

Comment: ошибка в том, что я забыл поставть `;` в конец объявления rand)

Comment: @wololo, в следующий раз учту, просто был уверен, что ошибка не в них т.к. принтВаня создаёт параграф с классом и заданным в скобках текстом, а рандом я проверял выводя числа в консоль, получались всегда число без плавающей точки и подумал то что нет смысла их писать.